# Looking for alternatives to MbUnit's parallel test, using [attributes]

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit, mbunit, pnunit

MbUnit uses the [Parallelizable(TestScope.*)] attribute for parallel tests, however I cannot use MbUnit because it seems to be discontinued (or soon to be discontinued).

I would like to do something similar with another testing framework, ideally PNUnit, but it could be anything else. What's the closest thing I can get to [Parallelizable(TestScope.*)] attribute for parallel tests in PNUnit? I looked at the documentation and found nothing quite similar. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: NUnit 3 [will support parallelization](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/66), and it is still very much under active development.  An alpha of v3 was released last week, so you could maybe try that out until it is production-ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like NUnit 3 alpha is a promising alternative to MbUnit.